# Hierarchical clustering on dependent data

Tags: clustering, repeated-measures, independence, hierarchical-clustering

I do customer clustering based on weekly data. I don't want to rely on only one week of data so I was considering pooling the data over a few weeks together and assume that these are simply "different" customers.

Point 3 here: http://www.statisticalassociates.com/clusteranalysis10.htm suggests that it is a mistake.

I know I should be cautious with dependency in the data but I am unable to find a proper reasoning on why would this pose a problem to hierarchical clustering.

Could someone give a proper explanation of why it is a problem? And possibly suggest strategies to overcome this.

Comment: No, I don't think taking different repeated measures for different individuals is by default a mistake in cluster analysis. Most of clustering methods, including the hierarchical one, are not statistically model-based; they can't and don't adjust for within- and between-subject factors. However, the consideration is _on you_. When you cluster a set of objects which is a mix of different individuals and same individuals measured twice - you must be aware of the potential bias since same individual cases are usually more similar.

Comment: (cont.) So, objecting to word "mistake", I'd rather say "your resposibility", you must be aware what you are doing and how it could affect results.

Comment: If have a dataset mix as I've mentioned before you might want to request that cases representing same individuals necessarily fall in same cluster in hierarchical agglomerative clustring (HAC), i.e., they merge early by compulsion. While it is possible to do in stages with standard HAC functions, there exist implementations which allow to do it right within single run (an example is my macro `!hieclu` for SPSS.